# how to conditionally display the innerHTML values using pipe

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using angular 8. Wanted to conditionally implement the **innerHTML** using pipe translate.

**.html**

```
<button type="button"     
    mat-flat-button
    // using translate module internally
   [innerHTML] = "display ? (HIDE_NUMBER' : SHOW_NUMBER) | translate)"
   (click)="toggle()">
</button>
```

**.ts**

```
//all imports are done

   export class New implements OnInit {

    public display: boolean;

    constructor() {}

    toggle() {
      this.display = !this.display;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a strange `'` after `HIDE_NUMBER` :) . But that's not the only problem

You need to do something like this

```
[innerHTML] = " (condition ? 'translate_string'
                   : 'the_other_translate_string'
                ) | translate
                "
```

The idea is to wrap the condition inside `()` and then translate the `result` from that condition. That's why the `translate` pipe is outside the `()`

Comment: Glad i could help ! Cheers ! :D

Comment: yeah will accepts it only after few minutes of posting. Please Rate the Question Too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<button type="button"     
      mat-flat-button
      [innerHTML] = "(display ? 'HIDE_NUMBER' : 'SHOW_NUMBER') | translate"
       (click)="toggle()">
</button>
```

Comment: Typo, forgot to delete